# Odd behavior for NTFS symlinks? Can use "TYPE" but not "MORE"

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, ntfs, symbolic-link

I've created a symlink to a file on an NTFS file system (Windows 7). If I use the `more` command to view the file, it doesn't display anything. If I use the `type` command, it works as expected.

Here's what I did:

```
C:\Users\Foo\Documents\>mklink test c:\temp\filename.txt
```

Directory:

```
04/27/2020  10:20 AM    <SYMLINK>      test [c:\temp\filename.txt]
```

Now let's view it:

```
C:\Users\Foo\Documents\>more test

C:\Users\Foo\Documents\>
```

As we can see, there was no output from the `more` command. Alternatively:

```
C:\Users\Foo\Documents\>type test
This is the contents of filename.txt

C:\Users\Foo\Documents\>
```

Any ideas why `more` doesn't show the contents, but `type` does?

Comment: Try `%__APPDIR__%more.com test` and `%__APPDIR__%more.com <test` 
and see what happens, just to make sure more.com (windows) is being used, and not another executable present / found in `% path%` named `more.bat, .cmd,.vbs, exe, etc. ..`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `where more.com` verifies that it's coming from `c:\Windows\System32\more.com`. I think this is possibly a problem with how `more` looks for file handles.

Comment: so sorry my distraction, replace .com to .*